# How to import types for jquery in Ember with typescript?

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I would like to import the type JQuery.Event in order to use it in a click function.
What's the right way to do that? I've already looked it up on other sites, but cannot find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install the types from npm.

`npm i -D @types/jquery`